# How to make form responsive in css?

Tags: html, css, forms, responsive-design

I have a screenshot as shown below which I have to replicate in HTML/CSS. **The below screenshot should look exactly the same both in desktop and mobile view**.

[image]

At this moment, I am able to get this in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/237/embedded/result/) which **looks good in desktop  view** but I can see **white spacing at the right in mobile view**.

I think I need to make some changes in the below CSS codes but not sure if this is the right class which needs to be change.

```
.login-page .form .login-form .add-winner {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid #1173B7;
    background-color: white;
    color: #1173B7;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 25%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}

.login-page .form .login-form .save {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
    border: 1px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 35%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes **I should make in the CSS** in the fiddle so that the above design looks exactly the same both in mobile and desktop view.

At this moment, I am seeing white space at the **right in mobile view**.

Comment: Rather than using percentages, you should be using [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to specify different sizes at different breakpoints.

Comment: @APAD1 Thanks. I am wondering if you can update it in the fiddle.

Comment: @APAD1 I am bit unsure where I have to use the media queries and in which class

Answer (score 3):

Just change the CSS on line 52 in fiddle to:

```
.form {
background: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
max-width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto 100px;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 50px;
text-align: center;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 
0.24);
}
```

I have set a max-width for your form so that the width of the form is set to 500px as it crosses the 500px width. Otherwise, it will be 100% of the width of the browser area.

Comment: It worked for me. I have one more query. I am wondering if there is any way I can replace the white spacing from the bottom with the `background color: BFBFBF`. If you check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/237/embedded/result/) there is white spacing at the bottom. I want to replace that white spacing with the `background color: BFBFBF`

Comment: Update your CSS for body and .login-page:
body{
       height: 100%;
      }
.login-page {
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 100%
}

Answer (score 2):

Your `form` element has a static width of 500px set.

Change it to something like:

```
form {
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It may also be helpful to add this so the padding is included with the width calculations:

```
form {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```